# Horizontal accuracy higher than 200

Tags: ios, swift, location, cllocationmanager

I need to know the user’s exact location, but underground in the metro the LocationManager gives back false location.

For example we’re between Station 1 and Station 2 underground.. then the gps signals will find their ways out of the tunnel and since the nearest “exit” is Station 1 then between the two stops the LocationManager will think we’re still at station 1.

Underground the horizontalAccuracy is between 200-1500

Outside on the streets it is between 10-200

To prevent incorrect locations should I check

```
if location?.horizontalAccuracy > 200 || location?.horizontalAccuracy == -1 )
    doNotSaveLocation()
}
```

Is this a good Idea or not?

Comment: That seems reasonable, although you might not want to hard code "200" so you can configure the minimum accuracy you are willing to accept.

Comment: @JeremyP how could I do that? In my code desireAccuracy is set to nearestTenMeter

Comment: Core Location is not my area of expertise. Hence the reason I wrote a comment not an answer - I was guessing a bit. Probably best to wait for somebody who knows what they are talking about :-)